# file system recognition on Windows and BIOS parameter block position

Tags: windows, filesystems, sector

I am writing a boot sector for the FAT12 file system for a floppy disk.

**Code #1:**

```
start: jmp main
TIMES 3 - ($-$$) DB 0
OEMname: DB '12345678'
;rest of the BPB information below
```

**Code #2:**

```
TIMES 3 - ($-$$) DB 0
OEMname: DB '12345678'
;rest of the BPB information below
```

In both these cases, `OEMname` starts from byte 3 (as informed by the assembler listing).

When the boot sector is written to the disk, Windows recognizes the partition when code #1 is used but fails to recognize when code #2 is used, i.e. it complains that the drive is not formatted.

Why does Windows succeed to identify the file system in one case but not the other?

Comment: Because it checks the first bytes for some common values.

Comment: Yes. I have the TIMES keyword for that to align the BIOS parameter information. The map file indicates that the BIOS Paramter Block starts from byte 3 for both the code. For the second code, TIMES keyword is supposed to pad the code with 0s to ensure that BPB starts from byte 3. For the first code, BPB automatically starts from byte 3. The TIMES keyword is redundant but the expression given to TIMES is 0 so the assembler adds nothing. In both cases, BPB starts from byte 3.

Comment: @YashasSamaga : Windows is actually checking what is in the first 3 bytes to decide. As Jester said it is looking for some common values (like a near JMP). It is likely doing that to decide whether a BPB is present in the boot sector. Some BIOSes will make a similar check.

Comment: "The first three bytes EB 3C 90 [...] code matching this pattern (or using the E9 jump opcode) is required to be present by [...] Windows" [source](http://wiki.osdev.org/FAT)

Comment: Oh. Wow. I just changed TIMES 3 - ($-$$) DB 0 to TIMES 3 - ($-$$) DB 1 and it worked.

Comment: @Jester Can you post it as the answer so that I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: That means your system just checks for non-zero. For compatibility, you should use the jump though.

Comment: @Jester still interested in posting an answer?